# Tagged inconsistent between page & API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

I'm seeing inconsistent results between my page's tagged posts on the web and the API.  Some of the mentions are not showing up in the API.  Any suggestions?

I'm making the API call with `manage_pages` permission.

From the web

[image: From the web]

From the API. Notice "Ignore this mention...." is missing.

[image: From the API]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure none of the users that posted those messages have removed platform apps' ability to access their data? You can quickly check by attempting to access 
`https://graph.facebook.com/<USER ID HERE>`

If they've blocked your app or disabled all platform apps from their profile, the response will be:

> {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get
>   request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}.

Comment: There are two tags by me there.  One shows up in the API, one does not.

Comment: And can you access the post directly when using the same access token you're using to retrieve the /tagged connection?

Comment: Actually, the 'recent posts by others' box corresponds to the page's /feed connection (though it also has posts from the page itself), not 'tagged' - is there definitely a tag present in both messages?

Comment: Where do I find the post's object id?

Comment: Same problem with the feed, btw. And I have to sort through a lot more posts to get tagged posts.

Comment: It's also missing from my feed using my access token.

Comment: My access token didn't have `user_status` permission. *facepalm*

Comment: To be fair, my answer didn't really solve your issue then, you should  probably add a new answer and accept that

Comment: Did Facebook make you say that? ;-)

Comment: ha, no, but i'd rather the accepted answer was actually the solution to the question, and not just something that pointed you in the right direction